Alternative versions of a very basic fact
A very basic fact that nonetheless have always intrigued me since my first undergraduate studies (perhaps even before that, implicitly) is:
Let $a,b\in\mathbf{Z}$. Then $\text{gcd}(a,b)=1$ if, and only if, there are $x,y\in\mathbf{Z}$ such that $ax+by=1$.
Of course, such a basic fact is employed everywhere, so it's not terribly exciting to ask for a list of examples of its uses in math. I'd like rather to ask for its generalizations, or for any of its analogues.
The first that comes to everyone's mind, I guess, is: just replace $\mathbf{Z}$ with any PID and a generalization of this fact holds.
What other generalizations or analogues of it are there? I'm particularly curious about versions coming from number theory, but also algebra in all of its subfields.

There are versions with $\mathbb Z$ replaced by $\mathbb N$, though the condition becomes more complicated. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem .

This "basic fact" is Bézout theorem.
